# RewriteRule: problems with dash

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm using the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^colection/(\w+)/?$ collection.php?title=$1
```

Works great for me. But I would like to use a dash instead underscore between words. And thus, the site can not find the page (error 404).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you're getting 404 because `\w` in your regex matches only alphanumerics and underscore so it won't match hyphen.

Replace your RewriteRule with this:

```
RewriteRule ^colection/([^/]+)/?$ collection.php?title=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```